# Basic NodeJS/PostgreSQL program is outputing error: bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm writing a node.js code that should connect to a Postgres database and execute a query.

The problem is that an error is occurring when I execute the script: `bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0`.

I don't understand what is happening. Could someone help me?

Full script:

```
const { Client } = require('pg');

let connectionString = 'postgresql://ezert:<myPassword>@localhost:5432/mydb';

const client = new Client({
    connectionString: connectionString
});

client.connect();

client.query('select * from my_table', [1], function (err, result) {

    if (err) {

        console.log('[ERROR]:\n' + err);
        return;

    }

    console.log('[RESULT]:\n' + result.rows);
    return;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://node-postgres.com/api/client#client.query)

The query function recibe optional parameters

```
client.query(
  text: string,
  values?: Array<mixed>,
  callback: (err: Error, result: Result) => void
) => void
```

> Your query `select * from my_table` doesn't receive any parameter but you are supplying one **[[1](https://node-postgres.com/api/client#client.query)]**.

#### Option 1: Remove the paramter

```
client.query('select * from my_table', function (err, result) {
   // your code here
});
```

#### Option 2: Use the parameter in your query

For example:

```
client.query('select * from my_table where columnName=$1', [1], function (err, result) {
   // your code here
});
```

(columnName should be set to a column of my_table)

Answer (score 0):

> 'select * from my_table', [1]

Your query does not take any parameters (there are no $1, $2, etc. placeholders in the query text), yet are trying to stuff a single parameter, containing `1`, into it.

If your query takes no parameters, don't give it any parameters.